# How to get the data inside the json curly braces? Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, get, curly-braces

I can get the result and message data but I can't get the `crew_name` inside the `crew`. How can I get the data if it is inside the curly braces?

Json printed on console

```
  {
    crew =     {
        "crew_avatar" = "http://ec2-52-221-231-3.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/gv/images/profile_image/Pang_Kang_Ming_916210_0e9.jpg";
        "crew_contact" = 0123456789;
        "crew_email" = "pang@xover.com.my";
        "crew_gender" = Male;
        "crew_id" = PP000001;
        "crew_name" = "Pang Kang Ming";
        "crew_preferred_name" = PKM;
        "crew_qrcode" = "images/qrcode/qrcode_085960293a5378a64bec6ebfa3c89bb7.png";
    };
    message = "Login Sucessfully";
    result = success;
}

@IBOutlet var empNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var empIdLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let empNameValue = user!("crew"["crew_name"])as? String
    let empIdValue = user!["result"]as? String

    empNameLabel.text = empNameValue
    empIdLabel.text = empNameValue

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please add your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside the curly braces is a dictionary, you can access that by first creating a dictionary from the "crew" key, and then accessing "crew_name" through that.

Assuming that the `user` variable is correctly created with the JSON data you can do the following to access "crew_name":

```
if let crew = user!["crew"] as? [String:Any], let crewName = crew["crew_name"] as? String {
    print(crewName) // output: "Pang Kang Ming"
}
```

Comment: how if i want get multiple data? get "crew_name", "crew_id","crew_email"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize your JSON in order to use the properties inside the object. Refer to this [link](https://softwarejuancarlos.com/2015/12/20/swift-2-examples-10-serialization-tofrom-json-using-objectmapper/) where they use ObjectMapper to serialize and deserialize JSON Objects.

NOTE: Do read up on the [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) before using ObjectMapper

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize your JSON to an object You can use Swift's build it JSON serialization with [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) which is a bit cumbersome or use open source library like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

After you deserialize you will have an object that represents your JSON, then you can access it like you access any parameter of a class (if you will SwifyJSON), or you can access it like a dictionary

```
yourJSONObject["crew"]["crew_name"]
```